# O(n) time O(1) space substring search with bracket patterns

Tags: regex, language-agnostic, pattern-matching, substring

For fixed-substring search, there are exactly two known algorithms with O(n) runtime and O(1) working space: SMOA and Two-Way (see http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/). Both of them depend on having or imposing an ordering on the alphabet.

Suppose instead of searching for fixed substrings, I want to be able to search for any one of a set of substrings expressed with bracket expressions, e.g.

```
 [abc]d
```

would match "ad", "bd", or "cd". Assuming the alphabet is finite, the length of any bracket is bounded and thus any term of the form "length of a bracket" in the time or space requirement is O(1).

Is there a way to perform the search in O(n) time (where `n` is the length of the string to be searched, i.e. the "haystack") and O(1) working space?

Unless the solution involves somehow ordering bracket sets with the alphabet ordering, any solution to this problem would provide a new solution to the fixed-substring search problem in O(n)/O(1) without the ordering requirement, and thus seems very unlikely to exist.

Answer (score 0):

I must be missing something.  From your linked page, the brute force method is O(n).  It would appear that you could write what you are looking for every easily:

```
1.  Pattern is P with index p indicating which element of the pattern we are on.
2.  String is S with index s indicating which element of the string we are on.
3.  if S[s] matches P[p], increment both indicies and repeat until you complete the Pattern.
4.  If S[s] doesn't match P[p], set p=0 and increment p.
```

That would be O(n) and meet your requirements.

Comment: The brute force method is `O(nm)`, not `O(n)`.